# interactive algorithm line numbering hyperref

Tags: hyperref, algorithms, cleveref

I needed two algorithms where client-server interact. I wrote a figure with two minipages each containing an algorithm.

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.48\linewidth}
    \algrenewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{\AlgLyn{s}{algo:FigName}}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.48\linewidth}
    \algrenewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{\AlgLyn{c}{algo:FigName}}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\label{algo:FigName}
\end{figure}
```

I need lines of both the algorithms are numbered. Precisely, the client algorithm is numbered as (c101,c102,..., c110,c111) and the server algorithm is numbered as (s101,s102,..., s120,s121) where c-1-01 stands for client, this is 1st figure, 1th line etc. To identify each line such a way, I have used **fmtcount** package that allows zero-filling a string. I defined two macros:

```
\newcommand{\AlgLyn}[2]{#1\ref{#2}\padzeroes[\zfill]{\decimal{ALG@line}}:}
\newcommand{\AlgLyne}[3]{#1\ref{#2}\padzeroes[\zfill]{\decimalnum{\ref{#3}}}}
```

The first-one prints line numbers in the description of the algorithms as required.
The second one is used to refer to a particular line of the algorithm. For example, one can refer to the 5th line of server code by calling \AlgLyne{s}{algo:FigName}{line:5} if one already has labeled the 5th line by \label{line:5}.
It runs quite well even with **cleveref** included.

Now I face a problem when I try to include the package **hyperref**. The problem I am facing is two-fold:

1. Notice the s-1-05 (output due to \AlgLyn{s}{algo:FigName}), the 1 is coming due to \ref{#2} in \AlgLyn. Now,  is trying to add hyperlink to all the 1s i.e. all (s101, s102, s103,...) printed in the algorithm description, are dereferenced and a hyperlink is added to the algo:FigName. I don't want that. I want the way it was behaving previously. Like, in the description of the algorithm, the line numbers will be printed (s101, s102, s103,...) but without any hyperlink to algo:FigName.
2. The \AlgLyne{s}{algo:FigName}{line:5} fails with a message "Missing number, treated as zero". I don't know exactly why it is failing?

In case, these are intrinsic limitations of the way I have defined the two macros above, please suggest some other way so that I can get the following:

1. server-client interactive algortihm with line number in (c101,..., c111),(s101,..., s121) the algorithm description.
2. No compatibility issue with **cleveref**.
3. No compatibility issue with **hyperef**. That too only when I define a label, \AlgLyne will show the line number and **hyperef** will put a hyperlink to that particular line.

I am attaching two pics of the current situation.

1. This is due to \AlgLyn{c}{algo:FigName-3} and \AlgLyn{s}{algo:FigName-3}  printing line number to each line of the algorithm. [image: Pic-1]
2. This is due to \AlgLyne{s}{algo:FigName-3}{line:3} referring to a particular line of the algorithm.[image: Pic-2]

Note: As per egreg's request, I am posting an example code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{algpseudocode
\usepackage[lined,linesnumbered,commentsnumbered]{algorithm}
%\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithm}
\def\zfill{2}
\newcommand{\AlgLyn}[2]{#1\ref{#2}\padzeroes[\zfill]{\decimal{ALG@line}}:}
\newcommand{\AlgLyne}[3]{#1\ref{#2}\padzeroes[\zfill]{\decimalnum{\ref{#3}}}}
\newcommand{\rarrow}[2]{\xrightarrow{\makebox[#1]{$#2$}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
     \algrenewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{\AlgLyn{c}{algo:FigName}}
     \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \caption*{Client}
        \begin{scriptsize}
             \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                   \State{$K_i\leftarrow F(K, z_1||i)$ for $i\in[0,2]$; ${\sf Msg}\leftarrow \bot$}
                   \Statex{\hspace*{0.64\linewidth}$\rarrow{0.5\textwidth}{\Phi}$}%
            \For{$c=1,2,\ldots$} \label{cli-cstart}
                \For{$\alpha\in[2,n]$}
                    \State{$X[c,\alpha]\leftarrow g^{F_p(K_Z,z_1||c)F_p(K_X,z_\alpha)}$}
                \EndFor
           \EndFor   \label{cli-cend}
    \end{algorithmic}
        \end{scriptsize}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
\algrenewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{\AlgLyn{s}{algo:FigName}}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
        \caption*{Server}
        \begin{scriptsize}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State{$Answer\_Set\leftarrow \phi$}
        \Statex\Statex
        \For{$c=1,2,\ldots$} \label{srv-cstart}
            \State{$List[c]\leftarrow c$}
        \EndFor         \label{srv-cend}
    \end{algorithmic}
        \end{scriptsize}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Client Server Conversion}
\label{algo:FigName}
\end{figure}
\AlgLyne{c}{algo:FigName}{cli-cstart}

\AlgLyne{s}{algo:FigName}{srv-cend}
\end{document}
```

`

\AlgLyne{c}{algo:FigName}{cli-cstart} produces c102 and \AlgLyne{s}{algo:FigName}{srv-cend} produces s104. I need [c102] or [s304] hyperlink.
If we uncomment hyperref,

1. Get error "Missing number, treated as zero"
2. In place of hyperlink to c102 or s304 line, we sometimes get hyperlink at c[1]0[2] and s[1]0[4].
3. All the lines of above the algorithms sometimes get hyperlinked line number looks like c[1]01, c[1]02, c[1]03, and so on.

Comment: Please, can you make the code snippet into a full compilable example to play with?

Comment: Hey @egreg, I have added the code snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exploit `refcount` and the arithmetic capabilities of TeX with `\numexpr`. In order to get unique identifiers, also `\theHALG@line` should be defined.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[lined,linesnumbered,commentsnumbered]{algorithm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithm}

\newcommand{\AlgLyn}[2]{%
  #1\the\numexpr\getrefnumber{#2}*100+\arabic{ALG@line}\relax
}
\newcommand{\AlgLyne}[3]{%
  #1\the\numexpr\getrefnumber{#2}*100+\getrefnumber{#3}\relax
}
\newcommand{\AlgoRef}[3]{%
  \hyperref[#3]{#1\the\numexpr\getrefnumber{#2}*100+\getrefnumber{#3}\relax}%
}

\newcommand{\rarrow}[2]{\xrightarrow{\makebox[#1]{$#2$}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
\algrenewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{\AlgLyn{c}{algo:FigName}}
\makeatletter\newcommand\theHALG@line{c\arabic{ALG@line}}\makeatother
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption*{Client}
\scriptsize
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State{$K_i\leftarrow F(K, z_1||i)$ for $i\in[0,2]$; $\textsf{Msg}\leftarrow \bot$}
  \Statex{\hspace*{0.64\linewidth}$\rarrow{0.5\textwidth}{\Phi}$}%
  \For{$c=1,2,\ldots$} \label{cli-cstart}
    \For{$\alpha\in[2,n]$}
      \State{$X[c,\alpha]\leftarrow g^{F_p(K_Z,z_1||c)F_p(K_X,z_\alpha)}$}
    \EndFor
 \EndFor   \label{cli-cend}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
\algrenewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{\AlgLyn{s}{algo:FigName}}
\makeatletter\newcommand\theHALG@line{s\arabic{ALG@line}}\makeatother
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption*{Server}
\scriptsize
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State{$\mathit{Answer\_Set}\leftarrow \phi$}
  \Statex\Statex
  \For{$c=1,2,\ldots$} \label{srv-cstart}
    \State{$\mathit{List}[c]\leftarrow c$}
  \EndFor         \label{srv-cend}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Client Server Conversion}
\label{algo:FigName}
\end{figure}

\AlgoRef{c}{algo:FigName}{cli-cstart}

\AlgoRef{s}{algo:FigName}{srv-cend}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @egreg. I know almost nothing about the usage of numexpr. Can you please share some document/link regarding this with ample example?